# Transfer Learning "from scratch"

Tags: conv-neural-network, overfitting, supervised-learning, transfer-learning, pre-training

I've recently started to work in machine learning and this is my first post here. Excuse me in advance for duplicates and/or slang mistakes. My question is about transfer learning (although in this case, I think it is more accurate to call it pre-training).

I'm working in a classification problem using a convolutional neural network. I have a dataset $A$ that is not large enough to train my CNN from scratch, I tried and my model overfits instantly. Looking for a solution I read about transfer learning and I'm trying to do it by myself because my CNN model is not one of the popular ones (AlexNet, ResNet50, GoogLeNet, ...), it is a custom one, so I cannot load pretrained weight that are available for those.

I searched for similar data, and made it to another dataset $B$ which I think that could be useful to pre-train my model (or transfer learning from $B$ to $A$). So, how should I train my model on dataset $B$? Should I split $B$ in train-val? Should I look for accuracy in val set? What if my model also overfits $B$?

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.